# inputs in form created with foreach in PHP, how to pass all input values with post method?

Tags: php, html, session

I created a form, where my inputs are created by a foreach loop with data coming from a mysql database.

When the form is submitted with method post, I want to be able to receive all the info through $_POST, but currently I'm only receiving the info from the last created input in the foreach loop.
The variable $fishes comes from mysql database and contains 8 rows, so the foreach loops 8 times.

My goal is to insert this data in a database table, so I can recall it.
When i run my XDebug after pressing submit, my $_POST contains action: insertFish and quantity: (value from input of last iteration in foreach).

[image: my global Post]

I would also like to be able to see the label with the corresponding quantity. I thought by adding a label would work but it didn't.

My form:

```
<form class="fishadd__form" action="index.php?page=fishtanks&id= <?php echo $_SESSION['tank_id']; ?>" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="insertFish">
<div class="fishadd__box--wrapper">

<?php foreach($fishes as $fish): ?>
  <div class="fishadd__box">
    <h2 class="fish__name"><?php echo $fish ['name']?></h2>
    <img class="fish__picture" src="../src/assets/img/goldfish.svg" alt="Goldfish" width="125">
    <div class="item__counter">
      <div class="fishadd__bottom">
      <button class="minus__button">-</button>
      <label for="quantity" name="<?php echo $fish['name']?>">
      <input class="fishadd__input" type="number" name="quantity" min="0" value="0">
      </label>
      <button class="plus__button">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="add__fish" value="submit">add to tank</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Did you try to add dynamic names to your input fields?

Comment: The name for each input has to be unique or an array, or else you're going to have a lot of conflicts.

Comment: I will try using the names from the database as the name for the inputs, like i did with the label

Comment: Unique names for the input field was the fix! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, **unique names for the input fields** was the fix. I solved it with an array that is looped inside the foreach:

`<input class="fishadd__input" type="number" name="<?php echo $fish['name']?>" min="0" value="0">`